# if I only have one component, is it safe to use AWT in a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have heard quite a few times not to mix `Swing` and `AWT` (heavyweight and lightweight) components.

But what if I will have no more than say, one component showing on the `JFrame` at one time. So far what I've seen the main thing is that `AWT` components are **always** on top, but as I said before, if I only will have one component on a `JFrame` at once what does it matter?

**EDIT**: all I need to do is paint with an `AWT` `Canvas`. I am using this for a game, so I'll need a `BufferStrategy`.

So I guess my question is: Is there still a compelling reason to not mix `AWT` and `Swing` components even if your only displaying one component on the `JFrame` at once?

**Also**, I already have it working just fine with just a `Canvas` in a `JFrame`, so what are the advantages of moving to Swing?

thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Why not go AWT entirely?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe I guess I could go that way. But I don't get setDefaultCloseOperation so I'd have to make a Listener to close it. But I guess that wouldn't be too hard so whatever.

Comment: That's 4 lines of code, give or take :) Use a WindowAdapter class

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe actually I did think of it now that I think of it : )

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Well I might need a JPanel if I make some kind of program crash screen. But I guess there could be alternatives. But I have asked the question so I would still like to see the results.

Comment: @AidanMueller : When using Swing, don't `Paint` on `Canvas`, instead use `JComponent` or `JPanel` and paint inside the `paintComponent(...) `method of the said thingy. [Painting in Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) :-)

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe The reason I asked this question is because I've used Canvas in JFrames before, and it's worked fine, so why not.

Comment: you can compare plain [JComponent](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9258934/714968) with Canvas, JPanel is separate and another level

Comment: @mKorbel what about a `BufferStrategy`?

Comment: @Aidan Mueller sorry I never used BufferStrategy or ColorModel, my interest, experiences and maybe knowlenge is about plain JComponents its methods and listeners, separate category is Look and Feel for Swing, and if is possible then I avoiding to touch anything about Graphics and painting as well as is possible :-), sure you forgot to mentioned there your real reasons and whats you expecting

Comment: @mKorbel I guess I'll just use Captain Giraffe's first suggestion: use entirely AWT.

Comment: maybe you are wrong, there are lots of usage of paintComponent for Swing JComponent, if your game will be based on hard graphics event, then you can still to choose betweens to override the RepaintManager or use the AWT Canvas, sure AWT is plain, easy and without unwanted suprices

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- you have to use AWT Components for hight performance painting, multimedia or vectoring the Graphics from OpenGL, CAD/CAM e.i.
- you can use AWT Components together with Swing JComponents only if you have got really important reason(s), for example a.m. point or event(s) from Swing is/are buggy or regular bug in the BugParade
- I'd suggest don't mixing AWT with Swing and vice versa
- advantage of AWT Components they are based on resources that came from Native OS
- dis_advantage of AWT Components that their development ended in the last century
- Swing is based or inherits of AWT Components and their methods

Answer (score 3):

> ..is `JPanel` the best Swing replacement for `Canvas`?

Yes, but override `paintComponent(Graphics)` rather than `paint(Graphics)`

Comment: +1 because your answer was helpful. But as I just edited, I need to use a `BufferStrategy`.

Answer (score 2):

As with most decisions, it's really a matter of what is important to you. Mixing AWT and Swing has performance drawbacks, and if you are trying to use themes, you will also run into problems.  That being said, there's no reason not to do this if it's what you require.

Swing is built on top of AWT, and, yes, it is newer and faster and better, but it's still got access to everything AWT has.

The real question here should be if there's a way to do what you need to do without using AWT?  Give us some pointers about what you need to do, perhaps there's a way to do it with Swing.

Comment: I did what you said and added an explanation of what I'm doing.

Comment: Hi Aidan, you want to paint with an AWT canvas? Is there any particular things you wish to do? Swing can also do something similar if you override the paint() method.