# Graphics Not Drawn/Appearing

Tags: java, swing, layout, paintcomponent, jcomponent

I'm having this problem where an object that I've drawn isn't appearing in the GUI. I know it's being processed because data is being pushed to a log file. However, the graphic isn't appearing.

Here's some of my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   JFrame window = new JFrame();
   window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
   window.setVisible(true);
}
```

There's a button and a few other widgets that I've placed here and there. The center pane (BorderLayout.CENTER) is where my `DrawnObject` is to be displayed.

```
// Called when button is pushed/clicked
public static void trigger()
{
   DrawnObject shape = new DrawnObject();
   window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
   window.getContentPane().add(shape, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   window.pack;
}

public class DrawnObject extends JComponent()
{
   @Override
   public Dimension getMinimumSize()
   {
       return new Dimension(100, 100);
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize()
   {
       return new Dimension(500, 500);
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getMaximumSize()
   {
       return new Dimension(700, 700);
   }

   @Override
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
   {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.setColor(Color.RED);
      g.fillRect(10, 10, 10, 10);
   }
}
```

I've tried casting the `Graphics` object as `Graphics2D` and using the appropriate draw methods, but that hasn't helped.

Comment: why `invalidate()`? Have you tried to use `revalidate()` instead?

Comment: `revalidate()` is not a method in `JFrame`.

Comment: Have you tried adding your `DrawnObject` to the JFrames content pane instead? (`window.getContentPane()`). 
Besides, why are you using invalidate in the first place? Your problem could be that your window has a `null` layout after you call `invalidate()`, and therefor not gets painted...

Comment: I'm used to using `invalidate()` to re-draw layouts and graphics, but adding to the content pane isn't working either.

Comment: the error is in the code you are _not_ showing - consider posting a SSCCE

Comment: Have you tried using `repaint()`?

Comment: @FlorianMinges I had originally used both `invalidate()` and `repaint()`, but neither worked (either separately or together).

Answer (score 4):

Try changing the color...

```
super.paintComponent(g);
g.setColor(Color.RED);
g.fillRect(10, 10, 10, 10);
```

The graphics context color is set to the components background color by default

[image]

```
public class PaintTest01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PaintTest01();
    }

    public PaintTest01() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new DrawPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class DrawPane extends JPanel {

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(30, 30);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(10, 10, 10, 10);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATED**

From your updated code in your question, it can't compile...

You create a `JFrame` named window in the constructor, which is a local variable...

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   JFrame window = new JFrame();
   window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
   window.setVisible(true);
}
```

Then you try and add the `DrawObject` to the window...

```
public static void trigger()
{
   DrawnObject shape = new DrawnObject();
   window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
   window.getContentPane().add(shape, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   window.pack;
}
```

But because `window` is undefined, you example can't compile.

The only way that this would compile is if you had a static variable at the class level called `window`, which in that case, it should be producing a `NullPointerException`, unless you've initialised that variable

```
public class MyDrawing {
    public static JFrame window = new JFrame();
```

This would mean you have two frames, one you created in the constructor and one your create as a static level class field.  This won't work, because they are different instances

Answer (score 3):

- have to return [PreferredSize from public class DrawnObject extends JComponent(),](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9258934/714968) otherwise returns `Dimension(0, 0);`
- `Top-Level containers` have got implemented `BorderLayout`, then `window.add(shape, BorderLayout.CENTER);` is proper code line and `JComponent` should be layed correctly
- use `pack()` instead of `invalidate()`, this code line doesn't works, to invoke something for container layed by `BorderLayout` or `GridLayout` (e.i. ???), nor for container based on `JComponent`,`JComponent` havent implemented any `LayoutManager` in `API`, have to return `PreferredSize`
- for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: `pack()` doesn't seem to work for me as it just compacts my GUI (taking one of my widgets out of view, by the way), but does not display the `DrawnObject`.

Comment: please is/are there something different with my linked code or nice example by @MadProgrammer,

Answer (score 1):

Try adding your `DrawnObject` to the windows content pane, and also don't forget to set a layout. Using a null layout is bad practice (your layout is set to null if you call on invalidate).

```
window.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
window.getContentPane().add(shape, BorderLayout.CENTER);
window.pack();
window.setVisible(true);
```

Also, try to skip the `invalidate()`.

Comment: For me, `window.getContentPane().pack()` is not a recognized method.

Comment: My `DrawnObject` didn't draw and my window shrank to the point where my original button disappeared as well. '_';