# JPanel filling entire JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am writing a simple game withing which I am using a JFrame which contains a grid and a JPanel.
Here is my pseudo code:

```
void MyJframeConstructor()
{
  // some basic bootstrap logic
  // calling repaint to draw grid
  repaint();

  // Grid is drawn fine.
  // Showing user a confirm dialog box on which I add below JPanel.

  if(confirmed)
  {
   // GameInfoPanel extends JPanel.
    infoPanel = new GameInfoPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    infoPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
    infoPanel.setLocation(500, 50);
    this.add(infoPanel);
    infoPanel.validate();      
  }
}
```

My problem here is my JFrame or window is 480 x 680.
Within this I am drawing a grid in 480 x 480 area.
Below which I want the JPanel to be located at 500,50 with dimension 400, 100.
However, when I run this code, once the user confirms with OK, the JPanel fills up the entire JFrame.
How can I keep the panel in its location and consistent in size through out the life of the app ?
Any help is highly appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the layout of the parent container (the `JFrame`)?  Could you post a SSCE? http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Within this I am drawing a grid in 480 x 480 area.

- override [PreferredSize for JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9258934/714968)
- then call `JFrame.pack()` and `JFrame.setVisible(true)` as last code lines
- have to read [InitialThread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)
- if is there only one `JPanel` (`JPanel filling entire JFrame`) then to use [built_in `BorderLayout` in `JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) f.e. `myFrame.add(infoPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER)` not FlowLayout
- don't to extend `JFrame` create this `Object` as local variable

Comment: doing this results in my JFrame becoming exactly the same size as my panel i.e. 400, 100 :(

Comment: nobody can to see your code, no ideas, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, sure could be based on code linked in my answer, JFrame has Borders & Toolbar came from Native OS

Comment: sorry for not posting a SSCE. Although myFrame.add(infoPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH) did the trick. Thank you @mKorbel.