# My JFrame size doesn't match up with set size

Tags: java, swing, jframe, collision-detection, game-physics

I am using `frame.setSize(480, 400)` to set the size of my JFrame. Despite this, when I am doing some collision checking (I am making a breakout game), the ball goes completely off the bottom of the screen, then finally bounces. This is the collision code I'm using: `if (YPos + height >= MainClass.height) { YVel = YVel * -1; }`. The static height variable is what is set to 400, and used in the `frame.setSize` call. This has happened in my pong game aswell, although I fixed it with some hard set values. I wouldn't like to repeat this though, as this is bad practice.

Thanks for any responses, Rees.

Comment: Please post more code. Have you a canvas ? Into another JPanel ? Use getWidth() and getHeight() on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. don't to set `frame.setSize(480, 400)` or `frame.setPreferredSize(480, 400)`
2. for painting to use `JPanel` / `JComponent`, then return coordinates from this container
3. painting in Swing by default never returns any `PreferredSize` [have to override `PreferredSize` for `JPanel` / `JComponent`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9258934/714968), (see `dim.width`, `dim.height` this methods returns proper coordinates for `Object`(s) added to `JPanel` / `JComponent`, after resize too)
4. then call (last code lines) `JFrame.pack()` and `JFrame.setVisible(true)`

5.`JFrame` doesn't returns proper coordinated have to calculating with its `Borders` and `Toolbar`, but `ContentPane` return inner and proper size

Answer (score 1):

Frames have borders.  These borders sit INSIDE the available space provided, meaning the available space for contents is the `frame size - border insets`

Instead, set the preferred size of the content and use `JFrame#pack` to compute the frame size

Check out

- [How can I set in the midst?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734069/how-can-i-set-in-the-midst/13734319#13734319)
- [Graphics rendering in title bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313084/graphics-rendering-in-title-bar/13316131#13316131)

For some examples and more details