# Java JFrame setSize induces lag

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, frame-rate

I have a simple thingy that I'm testing out with Java.

```
package us.superdisk.Teststs;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.PointerInfo;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
    JFrame jf = new JFrame("test");
    jf.setVisible(true);

    //jf.setSize(new Dimension(512, 512));

    Graphics g = jf.getGraphics();

    PointerInfo a;
    while (true) {
        a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
        g.drawLine(0, 50, (int)a.getLocation().getX(), (int)a.getLocation().getY());

    }

    }
}
```

This draws a line to the Mouse cursor.

When it is created, the window is incredibly small and invisible, you have to resize it to see the line. However, the line drawing is smooth and fluid.

When you uncomment the `setSize` bit, the line drawing is much laggier than if it wasn't... This doesn't make much sense to me? What is the problem?

Comment: You should implement a `MouseMotionListener` for the same task, it would be much more efficient than polling in an infinite loop.

Comment: Ouch, and amen to that!

Comment: And never get Graphics on a component via `getGraphics()` (except in very special circumstances, such as printing or if you need to draw the component on a BufferedImage). The tutorials will show you the best way to do this.

Comment: And don't call `setSize()` on anything. Instead override `getPreferredSize()` of a JComponent-derived object and call `pack()` on the JFrame.

Comment: 1. and never to use Graphics g = jf.getGraphics();, 2. nice shot to the dark, not real question, 3. [rest is in my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15042257/714968)

Comment: Seems like I'm doing a lot of stuff wrong.

Comment: @SuperDisk: no, think of it differently: you're in the process of learning to do things right. :)

Answer (score 2):

[`LinePanel`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5797965/230513) is an example of the approach suggested in several helpful comments about your question. The example includes key binding, so you may want to focus on an earlier, simpler [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5797965/2).