# move a panel across screen

Tags: java, swing

Im simply trying to move a panel across the screen little by little by clicking it, I also want to know how to do it by clicking a specific button?

```
private void ActorMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

    float x =Actor.getAlignmentX();
    float y=Actor.getAlignmentY();
    x = x+1;
    Actor.setAlignmentX(x);
    System.out.println(x);
    invalidate();
    validate();
    repaint();     
   }
```

Comment: What is your current problem? What is not working? Please clarify your question. Assume that we can't see code not shown nor read minds.

Comment: Use proper Java naming conventions. Variable names DO NOT start with an upper case character. The variable name should be "actor".

Comment: Make that the component isn't under the influence of a layout manager

Answer (score 3):

Changing the alignment doesn't move a component. You need to invoke the `setLocation()` method of the component to move it.

You don't need invalidate(), valiate() or repaint(), Swing is smart enough to repaint the component when its location changes.

The code would be the same in a button. You create an ActionListener that has a reference to the component you want to move and then change its location.

Also, to randomly move components on a panel you will need to use a null layout. So you will also be responsible for initially setting the bounds of the component.

Lots of stuff here. If you need more help then you need to post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to show us what you have done so far.

Comment: int  x = Actor.getX();
       int y = Actor.getY();
       x = x+10;
       
       Actor.setLocation(x,y);
this code works, however how can I make it that if I click a specific button it moves?

Comment: I already gave you a suggestion. I also suggested if you have a problem then you need to post an SSCCE showing what you have done.

Comment: @WayneDaly : [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), is your friend in this case. Here is a related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9259657/1057230)