# JPanel is not displaying in my JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

so I'm playing with JPanels and JFrames and I'm noticing that the JPanel I created is not showing displaying when I add it to a Jframe object. Note, that when I created a JPanel in my Jframe constructor giving the jpanel parameters before being added to the Jframe, it worked. However now I'm using a JPanel object I created and it's not working anymore.
This is what I have done.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MyGui extends JFrame {

    MyMouseListener listen = new MyMouseListener();

    public MyGui() {
        setSize(500, 500);
        //setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        Panel panel = new Panel();
        add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        //setVisible(true);
        show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        MyGui gui = new MyGui();
    }
}

class Panel extends JPanel {

    MyMouseListener listen = new MyMouseListener();

    public Panel() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        addMouseListener(listen);
        setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);
        g.drawOval((int) Math.round(listen.p.getX()),
                (int) Math.round(listen.p.getX()), 1, 1);
    }
}

class MyMouseListener implements MouseListener {

    Point p = new Point();

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Mouse was clicked");
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        p = e.getPoint();
        System.out.println(p);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Actually I think I've found the error. The JPanel has it's paint method which when deleted allows the Jframe to show the panel. However I need to be able to draw stuff on the JPanel.

Comment: Call pack() or setSize() before showing the frame. If you add the panel after showing call revalidate(); repaint();

Comment: The only thing I changed in your code to see your panel was to change `super.paintComponents(g);` to `super.paintComponent(g);`. That still leave out your oval that isn't painted.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau So it looked liked this? public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
  super.paintComponent(g);
  g.drawOval((int)Math.round(listen.p.getX()), (int)Math.round(listen.p.getX()), 1, 1);
 }

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Because mine doesn't work.

Comment: `public void paint (Graphics g){
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.drawOval((int)Math.round(listen.p.getX()),     (int)Math.round(listen.p.getX()), 1, 1);
    }`, didn't mention changing anything else but that line. :)

Comment: Why you using `show()` and why not `setVisible(true)` ?

Comment: @MichaelNana : Please have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11372350/1057230)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

its

`super.paintComponent(g);`

Advice:

1)You are making things unnecessarily complex.
e.g to close the window you should use

`frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`

instead of the call to `System.exit(0);` and using window listeners

2)As said by @mKorbel , you should use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to start your gui as Java GUIs are supposed to run on EDT(Event Dispatch Thread) and should not run on main thread.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have apdated my code with the changes. Anyway, taking out super.paintComponent(g) still doesn't make the JPanel visible in the JFrame.

Comment: You don't have to take out anything.Just remove the **s** in the line `super.paintComponents(g);` inside your `paint`.Now it should look like `super.paintComponent(g);`.Then,it runs fine

Comment: I did that too and it still doesn't work. public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
  super.paintComponent(g);
  g.drawOval((int)Math.round(listen.p.getX()), (int)Math.round(listen.p.getX()), 1, 1);
 }

Answer (score 2):

1) `super.paintComponents(g)`; inside `paint()` could be

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    ....
}
```

2) don't to set any size `setSize(500,500)`; or `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));`, to use `pack()` and then (uncomment) `setVisible(true)` for JFrame and to override `getPreferredSize()` for `JPanel`

3)   `MyGui gui=new MyGui();` inside `public static void main(String []a){`, should be wrapped into `invokeLater`, more see in `Oracle tutorial Initial Thread`

Comment: There's a preferred size set to the `JPanel`, making `pack()` and `setVisible` work correctly.

Comment: @Jonathan Drapeau  [agree with final result, but isn't about good coding practicies](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9258934/714968)

Comment: @mKorbel Are you talking about the paintComponent inside the JPanel? because I have included the call to the super and commented it out and on both occasions the JPanel still didn't show up.

Comment: @Michael Nana see my linked code in above comment addressed to Jonathan Drapeau

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set the layout manager and add the panel to the contentPane instead of the JFrame itself ?

```
getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

Comment: You should always add your Panel to the contentPane anyway. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html

Answer (score 0):

Default Layout manager for frame is `FlowLayout` not `BorderLayout`. Try to `setLayout(new BorderLayout())` in your `MyGui` contructor.

Comment: Default `Layout` for `JFrame` is `BorderLayout` and not `FlowLayout`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set a Layout to your content pane. Try something like `getContentPane.setLayout(new Layout())`

View the oracle docs for details about layout managers: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html

Hope this helps