# fillRect Graphics error

Tags: java, swing, variables, graphics, paintcomponent

```
public class paintObjects extends JPanel{

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(25, 25, 100, 100); 
        g.fillRect(r.getX(), r.getY(), r.getWidth(), r.getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        }
```

I have an error on fillRect and when I hover over it, it says

> The method fillRect(int, int, int, int) in the type Graphics is not
>   applicable for the arguments (double, double, double, double

but I'm not sure how to fix this, if anyone could tell me how to. I'd be thankful.

Comment: for better help soner post an SSCCE/MCVE , short, runnable, compilable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

```
   public abstract void fillRect(int x, int y, int width, int height)
```

---

this is the method with parameter list

you need to cast double values to int because only int accept by method.

`r.getX()` returns double so cast it to `int` and pass to the method

```
 g.fillRect((int)r.getX(), (int)r.getY(), (int)r.getWidth(), (int)r.getHeight());
```

Comment: Thanks alot, this helped :) Will tick the answer in 9 mins

Comment: g.fillRect(r.getX(), r.getY(), r.getWidth(), r.getHeight());` returns `getPreferresSize` to `JPanel` by default, then there isn't required any casting to int

Comment: Oh, for some reason, the error went away. Once i finally compile the whole thing with the JFrame w/e i'll see if it gives out an error

Comment: [it could be](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9258934/714968), really tons code for JPanel + paintComponent + getPreferredSize in SSCCE/MCVE form here

Answer (score 0):

A couple of other options, both a little cleaner looking than casts:

Use the public fields of `Rectangle`, they are ints:

```
g.fillRect(r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height);
```

or just use `fillShape()` since Rectangle implements the `Shape` interface:

```
g.fillShape(r);
```