# Fill JPanel only to the height of inner elements

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I'm trying to achieve a design whereby one of my JPanel's heights is only set to the height of it's inner components. Currently it's laid out like so:

```
JPanel (BoxLayout)
    JPanel (CardLayout)
        JPanel (BoxLayout)
        JPanel (BoxLayout)
    JPanel (FlowLayout)
```

It currently displays as so, I want the top bit to expand the both on the x and y axis pushing the "Your Name" to above the status bar.

[image: Example UI]

I need to use BoxLayouts it seems so that it flows from top to bottom.

Please help!

Comment: Use `GridBagLayout` instead, it will give you the control to dictate how the space is allocated better

Comment: you have to [override getMin / Max / PreferredSize](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9258934/714968) for [BoxLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html), or to use [SpingLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html), better is the [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/)

Answer (score 1):

> I want the top bit to expand the both on the x and y axis pushing the "Your Name" to above the status bar.

Then is sounds like you can use a BorderLayout as the top level panel, instead of the BoxLayout.

Since the default layout manager for the content pane of the frame is a BorderLayout you can just add the panels directly to the content pane of the frame:

```
frame.add(cardLayoutPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.add(flowLayoutPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

When you add a panel to the "PAGE_END", its preferred height is respected.

When you add a panel to the "CENTER" it gets all the extra spaces available in the frame.

Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples.

> I need to use BoxLayouts it seems so that it flows from top to bottom.

You don't need to use a BoxLayout (as demonstrated above), but you can still use it if you want. BoxLayout respects the maximum size of a panel. So you could override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your panel using the flow layout to return the preferred height of the panel.

```
@Override
public Dimension getMaximumSize()
{
    Dimension preferred = super.getPreferredSize();
    Dimension maximum = super.getMaximumSize();
    maximum.height = preferred.height;

    return maximum;
}
```

Now the height of the flow panel will be respected and all the extra space will go to the other panel.